# `'pip wheel .` much slower than 'setup.py bdist_wheel`

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

With [this setup.py](https://gist.github.com/rosskarchner/828373043b6c8f4b724e89af937b4563) (not yet committed to the root of [this project](https://github.com/cfpb/cfgov-refresh/)) Python 2.7 , `pip wheel .` takes almost 20 minutes

```
$:~/projects/cfgov-refresh$ time pip wheel .                                                                                                     
   Processing /Users/karchnerr/projects/cfgov-refresh
   Building wheels for collected packages: cfgov
   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cfgov ... done
   Stored in directory: /Users/karchnerr/projects/cfgov-refresh
   Successfully built cfgov

    real    19m50.061s
    user    0m29.641s
    sys     1m21.651s
```

While `setup.py bdist_wheel` takes mere seconds.

```
rk@:~/projects/cfgov-refresh$ time python setup.py bdist_wheel
    [... ommited a bunch of noise ...]
    real    0m2.575s
    user    0m0.586s
    sys     0m0.309s
```

Any idea what accounts for such a big difference? Is there something I should be doing differently?

---

Using the `ts` command from moreutils, I can see that a huge chunk of the time is spent before pip even starts processing setup.py

```
[2017-01-17 15:41:36] Processing /Users/karchnerr/projects/cfgov-refresh
[2017-01-17 15:54:42]   Running setup.py     (path:/private/var/folders/_f/3lrtcs492pnbf6zcql9t0n380000gp/T/pip-p6TG9c-    build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///Users/karchnerr/projects/cfgov-refresh
```

Comment: Without the actual project, it's impossible to say.

Comment: @MattDMo updated the gist and question to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

- `pip wheel` insists on copying the entire project into a temp directory, using shutil.copytree
- copytree is pretty slow
- this repo has a *lot* of files.